# Ouput from Database for specific user

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

If I have a cart table for example with a list of cartIDs and Customer ID which is linked to a cart details table which contains the products for each cart etc.

If I want to output the cart for the user currently logged in would doing something like work?

```
SELECT FROM tblCart [CartID] AND tblCartDetail [title], [price],[image] 
WHEN CustomerID=CurrentlyLoggedInID
```

I know the SQL isn't correct but would that idea work? Or would it just output the whole cart for when the two values match?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is called a [SQL join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter, so CustomerID = @CurrentlyLoggedInID. Then set the parameter equal to the membership.getuser() string.

Comment: That's what I was thinking I just thought that is would return the whole cart table because  the two values both match

Comment: Using the WHERE clause (not WHEN by the way) acts as a filter. The query will only return records that match that filter. So, you would only get records where the CustomerID was identical to the value passed in the @CurrentlyLoggInID parameter. It would definitely NOT return all rows unless all of the rows had the same value in the CustomerID. :)